# Query records by date but exclude records if latest is not appropriate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to check how many employees were in a department at the start of the month.

I think I need to select records beginning of month or earlier, excluding the ones where the latest record's type is 2 (meaning termination) for an employee for a department

```
id  date    employeename    department  type
1   2016-03-01  Alpha   IT  1
2   2016-04-12  Alpha   IT  2
3   2016-04-15  Beta    Operations  1
4   2015-04-17  Gamma   IT  1
5   2016-04-23  Delta   IT  1
6   2016-05-01  Epsilon IT  1
7   2016-05-02  Delta   IT  2
8   2016-05-18  Gamma   IT  2
9   2016-05-21  Beta    Operations  2
10  2016-05-31  Zeta    IT  1
```

In this example, for the IT department's employees for <= 2016.05.01 should be

```
4 2015.04.17 Gamma IT Hiring
5 2016.04.23 Delta IT Hiring
6 2016.05.01 Epsilon IT Hiring
```

because Alpha was already terminated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
USE sandbox
GO

declare @t table (id int, dte  date,   employeename varchar(10),    department varchar(10), type int)
insert into @t values
(1 ,  '2016-03-01',  'Alpha' ,  'IT' , 1),
(2 ,  '2016-04-12',  'Alpha' ,  'IT' , 2),
(3 ,  '2016-04-15',  'Beta'  , 'Operations' , 1),
(4 ,  '2015-04-17',  'Gamma' ,  'IT' , 1),
(5 ,  '2016-04-23',  'Delta' ,  'IT' , 1),
(6 ,  '2016-05-01',  'Epsilon', 'IT' , 1),
(7 ,  '2016-05-02',  'Delta' ,  'IT' , 2),
(8 ,  '2016-05-18',  'Gamma' ,  'IT' , 2),
(9 ,  '2016-05-21',  'Beta'  ,  'Operations' , 2),
(10,  '2016-05-31',  'Zeta'  ,  'IT' , 1)

select  *
from    @t 
where   employeename not in (select employeename from @t where type = 2 and dte <= '2016-05-01')
        and dte <= '2016-05-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a couple joined subqueries would work (they could also be saved views). This also gives you the functional pivot of having hire and term dates.

```
select a.id, a.date as hired, b.date as term, a.empName, a.dept from
    --hire date
    (select id, date, empName, dept from emp where type=1) a
join
    --term date
    (select id, date from emp where type=2) b
on a.id = b.id
where '5-1-2016' between hired and term
```

Comment: 1. With SQL Server you can't refer to column aliases in the where clause. 2. Using an inner join effectively excludes employees that have not been fired - you want to use a left join instead (but then you have to add another check for the case when term date is null). Using subqueries isn't needed at all - you can just join the tables together. 3. `id` is not the appropriate key to join the tables on, `employeename`  might be. It could look like this : https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/514762

Answer (score 0):

```
;with x as (
select *, row_number() over (partition by employeename order by date desc) rn
from @tbl
where date <= '20160501'
and department = 'IT'
)
select * from x where rn = 1 and type <> 2
```